# Insert new row inside to XWPFTable

Tags: java, apache-poi

i to try a make a application for insert new "work experience" inside to reference;

```
public class TestWordPOI {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InvalidFormatException, IOException {
        boolean add = false;

        XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument(OPCPackage.open(new java.io.File("C:\\Users\\luca\\Desktop\\CV_Europass_WvWinden.docx")));

        for (XWPFTable tbl : document.getTables()) {
            for (XWPFTableRow row : tbl.getRows()) {
                for (XWPFTableCell cell : row.getTableCells()) {
                    for (XWPFParagraph p : cell.getParagraphs()) {
                        for (XWPFRun r : p.getRuns()) {
                            String text = r.getText(0);
                            System.out.println("riga? :"+text);

                            if ((text!=null)&&text.contains("Work experience") ) {
//when i find "work experience" i need insert the new work experience
                           add=true;
                            }
                            if( add ) 
                                break;
                        }
                        if( add ) 
                            break;
                    }
                    if( add ) 
                        break;
                }
                if( add ) {

                    break;}         
            }
            if( add ) {

                XWPFTableRow row =tbl.createRow();   //
                row.addNewTableCell();
                XWPFTableCell cell = row.createCell();
                cell.setText("New work");

             row.addNewTableCell().setText("Code monkey");
                break;}


        }

        File output = new File("output.docx");
        document.write(new FileOutputStream(output));
```

the application insert the new "work experience" in bottom of page, i need insert this betwen a the last experience and the title Work Experience.
comebody know my mistake ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for (XWPFTable tbl : document.getTables()) {
            for (XWPFTableRow row : tbl.getRows()) {
                y++;
                for (XWPFTableCell cell : row.getTableCells()) {                
                   .
                   .
                   .
                   .

            if( add ) {
                XWPFTableRow row =tbl.createRow();

                 row.addNewTableCell().setText("some thing");

                tbl.addRow(row, y);

                break;}
```

i use 1 Counter for counting the row , when i find the work experience i use the counter for insert in the new row at corret linee